# Using pxssh to receive a parsed command output

Tags: python, pxssh

I need to use pxssh to ssh to a remote host and run a cmd and get returned output of the cmd that is parsed. Can someone provide a sample code for something like this? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: With only these details? Of course not. We have no idea what kind of parsing it is you want, no idea what subset of the protocol your remote host does or doesn't support (it's a lot easier if you can just use `exec_command()` and not need to parse out an individual command's output at all!), no idea what parts you've already successfully made to work and don't need help with, etc.

Comment: Asking for a prebuilt tutorial is simply off-topic here; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic; we expect questions to reflect a specific, narrow technical problem, where you've done all the work necessary to write code that generates that problem (and, where appropriate, a [mcve] letting us reproduce it and test our responses).

Comment: Thanks @charles duffy. I just found a solution online. I will keep this in mind. So next time it will be specific :)